# Oracle - Check if there is a data in range of date

Tags: oracle

I have three tables (receipts, receiptaddinfo, shops). I have select, that gives me a data with a all receipts from all shops since the declared date:

```
select *
from receipts r
join receipt receiptaddinfo ri on r.receiptid=ri.receiptid and r.shop=ri.shop
join shops s on ri.shop=s.shop and shoptype=0
where ri.creationtime >= '2016-05-19 00:00:00' 
order by ri.creationtime desc
```

The table shops, contain all shops, however, I want to check if there is a shop, which had no 'sale/receipts' since the declared date. Could somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT * from shops s 
WHERE s.shoptype = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 
 FROM  receipts r,
       receiptaddinfo ri
 WHERE r.receiptid = ri.receiptid 
 AND   r.shop = ri.shop
 AND   ri.shop = s.shop 
 AND   ri.creationtime >= '2016-05-19 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, that gave me what I wanted.